# How to have Chrome cover everything except the dock when double clicked?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

So I have recently switched to Mac from Windows and I like to have the dock always visible when I'm using programs (probably because I'm used to the Start button toolbar in Windows). I don't use the green full screen button, I just double click the title bar to make the window cover everything.

Unfortunately, this does not work in Chrome. Seems like the default shape of the Chrome window is set to be a square and when I double click on the title bar, it expands into a square, leaving space on the sides. I have to manually drag the left and right side to cover the screen.

Is there any way to change this?

EDIT: <kbd>Option</kbd> + Maximise does not work. It still leaves space on the sides.

Comment: I use "Moom" from the Mac App Store. See if that does what you want it to.

Comment: @TMHahn seems like that would do it but it costs £7.99. Don't want to spend that much just for this simple feature. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it looks like "Magnet" by CrowdCafé does the same thing for even cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key at the same time you click on the *Maximize* button on Chrome.  This will maximize the window while leaving visible the menu bar and dock.  This will also work on any other window on a Mac.

If this doesn't maximize the window on the first try, drag the window to where you want it (like you're doing now with the left and right sides) and then close the browser.  Next time you open it, it should fully maximize.

Comment: It doesn't, it just expands into a square. I think the default shape of the Chrome window will have to be changed.

Comment: See my recent edit.  I left out an important part.  This works perfectly on my Mac.

Comment: I know that works but somehow I always end up double-clicking the title bar by mistake while working, so it becomes small again. I have to keep doing it over and over again. I'm looking for a way so that it covers the screen by default.

Comment: This does cover the screen by default, each and every time I open Chrome.  I'm not doing anything special so I don't know why it's not working for you.  You can also look at an app name **Magnet** on the App Store.  It allows you to dynamically resize windows by moving them to the top/right/left.

Comment: It does work. I meant I am looking for a way for it cover the screen when I double click the title bar. I'll check out that app, thanks.